# How to sum parent model record from child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have two models such as Doctor & Patient.

```
Doctor model has many patients
Patients belongs to one doctor.
```

Each doctor has column called `fees(integer datatype)` which is to store the doctor fees. Each doctor has fixed fees like 10$, 20$ and so on.

Now I want to calculate the total fees for all patients. For example if 3 patients are exist with 3 doctors with fees 10, 20 & 30  respectively. Then total fees for all the patients will be 10+20+30 = 60. is their any way to do it sql without doing looping in rails code?

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has many :patients
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: doctor
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Do as below :-

```
# get first all doctors
doctors = Doctor.all
total_fees = doctors.inject(0) do |sum, doctor|
  # doctor.patients.count will give how many patients visited 
  # that specific doctor. With that count, I am multiplying that specific
  # doctor's fees, which is giving each doctors earnings from all his 
  # patients. # inject block then summing all doctors earnings and returned back.
  sum += doctor.fees * doctor.patients.size
end
total_fees
# => 60
```

If you like one liner -

```
doctors.inject(0) { |sum, doctor| sum + doctor.fees * doctor.patients.size }
```

After reading the post again, I came up with the below solutions(which is same as above, but no looping) :-

```
Doctor.joins(:patients).select("sum(doctors.fees) as total")[0].total # => 60
```

Here is another way and more efficient :-

```
Doctor.joins(:patients).sum("doctors.fees") # => 60
```

Comment: @loganathan try `Doctor.joins(:patients).select("sum(doctors.fees)")`.

Comment: I have tried this already, getting only Doctor relation array with nil values
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Doctor id: nil>]>

Comment: @loganathan `Doctor.joins(:patients).select("sum(doctors.fees)")[0]` will give you the answer.. try and tell me.

Comment: @arun I guess it wont, because the result is [#<Doctor id: nil>]>

Comment: @loganathan Please try now and let me know.

Comment: @arun I tried getting the output as #<Doctor id: nil>

Comment: @loganathan Did you try `Doctor.joins(:patients).select("sum(doctors.fees) as total")[0].total` ?